# Cannot get macOS Catalina to boot up into recovery mode on a VM

Tags: vmware-fusion, macos-catalina

I have a VM running MacOS 10.15 beta 2 (Catalina) on VMWare Fusion 11.

I want to boot it into recover mode.

I have tried holding down <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and I added `macosguest.forceRecoveryModeInstall = "TRUE"` to the `macOS.Catalina.vmx` file and none of these worked.

Has anyone had any success with this? If so, please share your tips. Any information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I wanted to disable SIP, I bypassed this by s`et csrutil` to disable during first recovery mode during installation the Catalina, once installed, you cannot get into it anymore

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but in my case I was using VMWare Player, so to run macOS on player you need to have [unlocker](https://github.com/paolo-projects/unlocker) properly installed and if its not then the VM will just get stuck in bootloop for both normal boot and recovery boot.

**So, I uninstalled my unlocker and then reinstalled it again and it worked :)**